# Chainlink functions : Failed to estimate gas for tx error (Foundry version)

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I have encountered an issue that I have been struggling with for some time now relating to the chainlink functions. I've been trying to call an API using the execute request function from foundry. However, I'm getting the following error when deploying TestChainlinkFunction script :

[⠘] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped
Script ran successfully.
SKIPPING ON CHAIN SIMULATION.

Finding wallets for all the necessary addresses...
Sending transactions [0 - 5].

Error:
**Failed to estimate gas for tx: 0x6931b6990cf430daf222f9e260416bb0aff977b3de68b46e0f6b612b6271930a**

Context:
(code: 3, message: execution reverted, data: Some(String("0x1f6a65b6")))

Below the deploy script :

```
contract TestChainlinkFunction is Script {
    uint256 deployerPrivateKey = vm.envUint("DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY");
    address deployerAddress = vm.envAddress("DEPLOYER_ADDRESS");

    function run() external {
        vm.startBroadcast(deployerPrivateKey);

        address wpAddress = 0x3D01BE50fB2f399EF01A8cB60AA6De174f91fCd2;
        address linkTokenAddress = 0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789;
        address linkPriceFeedAddress = 0x42585eD362B3f1BCa95c640FdFf35Ef899212734;
        address functionsOracleProxyAddress = 0x649a2C205BE7A3d5e99206CEEFF30c794f0E31EC;
        address registryProxyAddress = 0x3c79f56407DCB9dc9b852D139a317246f43750Cc;

        address wethAddress = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;

        // Functions

        WeightProvider weightProvider = new WeightProvider(
            functionsOracleProxyAddress,
            0x4367f2Bf724440df577cfc4349Edd72c9d9358a0,
            wethAddress
        );
        address weightProviderAddress = address(weightProvider);

        FunctionsBillingRegistry registry = FunctionsBillingRegistry(
            registryProxyAddress
        );
        uint64 subId = registry.createSubscription();

        IERC1363 linkToken = IERC1363(linkTokenAddress);

        console.log(linkToken.balanceOf(deployerAddress));

        console.log(subId);
        registry.addConsumer(subId, weightProviderAddress);
        weightProvider.setSubId(subId);
        linkToken.transferAndCall(
            registryProxyAddress,
            10 ** 18,
            abi.encode(subId)
        );
        console.log(linkToken.balanceOf(registryProxyAddress));
        weightProvider.executeRequest();

        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
```

Here is the code for the weightProvider contract that calls the executeRequest :

```
contract WeightProvider is Ownable, IWeightProvider, FunctionsClient {
    using Functions for Functions.Request;

    string public source =
        "const b=Functions.makeHttpRequest({ url:'https://www.signdb.com/.netlify/functions/optimize'});const c=Promise.resolve(b);return Functions.encodeUint256(Math.round(c.data['weight']));";
    INotary notary;
    uint64 subId;
    address wethAddress;
    uint24 poolFee = 3000;
    uint32 functionsGasLimit = 300_000;
    uint256 mostRecentWeight;

    constructor(
        address _oracleAddress,
        address _notaryAddress,
        address _wethAddress
    ) FunctionsClient(_oracleAddress) {
        notary = INotary(_notaryAddress);
        wethAddress = _wethAddress;
    }

    function setSubId(uint64 _subId) public onlyOwner {
        subId = _subId;
    }

    function setFunctionsGasLimit(uint32 _functionsGasLimit) public onlyOwner {
        functionsGasLimit = _functionsGasLimit;
    }

    function executeRequest() external override returns (bytes32) {
        require(subId != 0, "Subscription ID must be set before redeeming");
        Functions.Request memory req;
        req.initializeRequest(
            Functions.Location.Inline,
            Functions.CodeLanguage.JavaScript,
            source
        );
        return sendRequest(req, subId, functionsGasLimit);
    }

    /**
     * @notice User defined function to handle a response
     * @param requestId The request ID, returned by sendRequest()
     * @param response Aggregated response from the user code
     * @param err Aggregated error from the user code or from the execution pipeline
     * Either response or error parameter will be set, but never both
     */
    function fulfillRequest(
        bytes32 requestId,
        bytes memory response,
        bytes memory err
    ) internal override {
        uint256 weight = uint256(bytes32(response));
        uint256[] memory weights;
        Portfolio portfolio = Portfolio(notary.getPortfolioAddress());
        weights[0] = weight;
        weights[1] = 1 - weight;
        mostRecentWeight = weight;
        console.log(weight);
        portfolio.updateWeights(weights);
        // portfolio.updateAssets(_assetsAddress, _targetWeights, _decimals, _priceFeeds, _baseCurrencies);
        notary.updatePortfolio();
    }
}
```

Right now, it seems that the transaction is sent but is not confirmed. I followed all the steps to setup the request (subID, adding consumer, transfer and call ...). I can't seem to figure out what is missing. I also tried to manually set up high gas fees for the executeRequest function but I got the same error.

Any help on this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just double-checking, is your EOA address allowlisted? Have you tried, for testing purposes only, to set the gas limit to some crazy high value just to be sure that that's not the issue? The best approach here imo would be to use Foundry's debugger or some external tool like Tenderly to catch the actual function call that reverts, and then you can have a clearer picture